# MvvmCross AutoView dynamic dialog sections

Tags: android, dialog, touch, mvvmcross

I'm implementing a dialog view, using `AutoViews` that are available in `MVVMCross.AutoView`.

Does any one know if it is possible to create dinamic sections. e.g. Something like being able to bind the Elements list of a Section, to a notifiable list in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is not implemented currently within the Dialog part of AutoViews - just as it's not implemented in the source MonoTouch.Dialog or MonoDroid.Dialog

Adding INotifyCollectionChanged-aware sections to Dialog would definitely be possible, but it would require some skill and time to merge it into the Dialog core code.

If your list (ObservableCollection) is standalone, however - if it doesn't rely on sitting within a larger Dialog - then the list part of AutoViews should work OK for you.

You can see a list AutoView implemented in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CustomerManagement/CustomerManagement%20-%20AutoViews/CustomerManagement/ViewModels/CustomerListViewModel.cs - this works off of an `IObservableCollection` and seems to update as you add/remove customers.

---

Note that AutoViews is still very 'young' - and it'll remain so until we start getting a few more platforms working - there are people working on WP and WinRT Dialog implementations, but these are 'spare time' projects and the people are busy!

Comment: In my case it's not a standalone collection... The viewmodel that holds the collection, also has other models that need to be binded with the view. I think that for the moment I'll just make the app work with view development for each platform (Touch, Droid and maybe in a near future WP8). I'll definitly be on the lookout for new developments regarding AutoViews and, if I can, contribute to improve them.  Thanks